# j8583.xml looking for all the 128 fields

Tags: java, iso8583, j8583

I am very new to **j8583 library** and I'm using j8583 to parse and create ISO Messages. I am looking for the full *Data Elements XML Configuration* with the data type and the length of all the *128 fields*.

I really appreciate if some one can help with this matter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of j8583. The j8583 library can be configured to handle any type and length for field 128 or any other field (within the valid constraints of ISO8583 of course).

If you are implementing ISO8583 communication with some external system, you need to get their spec to know what type they are expecting. And make sure they will be returning that field, because I've found some implementations where they set bit 128 in the bitmap but they don't actually return that field, and that causes a parsing error. This is so common that I patched the MessageFactory, adding a flag to ignore field 128 if it is set in the map but doesn't actually appear in an incoming message.

Comment: The question was not about the field 128 but about the field definitions for all 128 fields.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the definitions of all 128 fields in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583#Data_elements). In configuration you need to specify supported fields per message type, which is provider-specific as @chochos mentioned.